# how to achieve pixelmath in numpy/scipy

Tags: python, image, numpy, scipy

I'm currently reading a book which uses pixelmath.

The problem is how can I do the following:

```
pmNewComputedImage("Ringing Paraboloid", 256,256,"(sqr(x)+sqr(y)) mod 256")
```

This will return an 256*256 image based on that equation `(sqr(x)+sqr(y)) mod 256`.

The idea is I'm not being able to do it in numpy. I'm still a newbie in numpy. I just need to know how to add the square of the rows to the column, mod it by 256 and return a new array.

Edit:

In pixelmath:

[image: pixelmath]

in numpy and matplotlib:

[image: numpy]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = np.arange(256).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.arange(256)
rng_paraboloid = (x*x + y*y) % 256

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(rng_paraboloid, interpolation='nearest')
```

[image]

In numpy-speak, the arrays `x` and `y` of shapes `(256, 1)` and `(256)` [broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to a common shape `(256, 256)`.

Comment: `x = np.arange(256).reshape(-1, 1)`
`y = np.arange(256)` you can do the following `x, y = np.ogrid[0:256, 0:256]` also. I updated my post above, please check both images. I did as you said. Any explanation for the first image?

Comment: Your description is wrong: `sqr` is not the square root, but the square, see my edit.

Comment: Btw, graphing your solution in OpenCV (cv2) gives the exact same result as the graph of the OP